# Divs adicionais com Ajax JSON não pegam o style

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Estou com um probleminha, fiz uma programação de blocos de portffolio onde que quando eu aperto em carrega mais o meu ajax cria os outros blocos do banco de dados.
Porem ele não está puxando o style que os blocos que ja estão no html tem, que seria a position absolute e o top e left para ficar um do lado do outro.
Para fazer esses style e animações uso o ISOTOPE.

CODIGO:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var loadedImageCount, imageCount;
$(function() {

    // GRID
    var $container = $('.grid');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.element-item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            horizontal: {
                verticalAlignment: 0.5
            }
        });
    });

    // filter functions
    var filterFns = {
        // show if number is greater than 50
        numberGreaterThan50: function() {
            var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
            return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
        },
        // show if name ends with -ium
        ium: function() {
            var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
            return name.match(/ium$/);
        }
    };


    // bind filter button click
    $('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        // use filterFn if matches value
        filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filterValue
        });

    });
    // change is-checked class on buttons 
    $('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
        var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
        $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $(this).addClass('is-checked');
        });
    });

    var loadedImageCount, imageCount;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        // add new images
        var items = getItems(function(html) {
            $container.prepend($(html));
        });

        // use ImagesLoaded
        $container.imagesLoaded()
            .progress(onProgress)
            .always(onAlways);

    });

});
// ----- ----- //

// return doc fragment with
function getItems(callback, items, contador) {
    if (!items) items = '';
    if (typeof contador == 'undefined') contador = 6;
    _getImageItem(function(html) {
        items += html;
        contador--;
        if (contador == 0) callback(items);
        else getItems(callback, items, contador);
    });

}



// return an <li> with a <img> in it
function _getImageItem(_callback) {
    var item = "";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "pegaPortifolio.php/?id=1", //?id="+idUltimo,
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success: function(data) {
            var pt1 = data.map(function(obj) {
                return '<div class="element-item ' + obj.menu + '" data-category="transition"><div style="padding:2.5px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"><a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="' + obj.imageM + '" alt="project 2"><div class="fundo-port"><h1>"' + obj.tipo + '"</h1><h2>"' + obj.nome + '"</h2></div></a></div></div></div>';
            }).join('');
            _callback(pt1); // <- aqui envias de volta para a callback da chamada da função
        }
    });
}



// triggered after each item is loaded
function onProgress(imgLoad, image) {
    // change class if the image is loaded or broken
    var $item = $(image.img).parent();
    $item.removeClass('is-loading');
    if (!image.isLoaded) {
        $item.addClass('is-broken');
    }
    // update progress element
    loadedImageCount++;
}

// hide status when done
function onAlways() {}

        </script>
```

Comment: Consegue montar um jsfiddle com o css e etc?

Comment: eu vou colocar o site no ar e vou editar para vc da uma olhada melhor...

Comment: ta dando uns problemas eu peguei esse pluguim aqui
isotope.metafizzy.com;
o css é pego pelo isotope.pkgd.js